# Spacing tool for joints - anyone know what the tool seen here is called?

Tags: tools, siding, joints, sheathing

Does anyone know what this tool seen at 4:48 is called? I tried searching for various names of what I thought it might be called but can't find anything. Or a similar tool would be fine - basically something that you can attach different size spacers depending on what gap you need.

https://youtu.be/BrrDp3gLOfI?t=288
[image]

Comment: an auto mechanic uses a similar tool that is called `feeler gauge`

Comment: I don't know what the tool is called. but equal spacing can be accomplished with a desired size nail, screw,  shim, or scrap wood...or many other things.

Comment: "Spacer" seems a good name. As in "Pass me the 1" spacer"

Comment: @jsotola I'm familiar with using feeler gauges to *measure* a gap; can you explain a situation where a feeler gauge is used to *set* a gap?

Comment: if you cannot measure a gap, then you cannot set it to a desired distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a siding gauge:

[image]
[siding gauge](https://www.bigrocksupply.com/simplesider-adjustable-siding-gauge.aspx?feed=Froogle&gclid=Cj0KCQiAtbqdBhDvARIsAGYnXBMbFDgbydpW2RaCKeNfGTIKJDiKeQILMN1PEvvdXLvcpOqdIviuoZoaAqqKEALw_wcB)

(Not a vendor endorsement.)